# Should you scale the FFT bins by $1/N$ where $N$ is the number of points in a transient signal?

Tags: fft

I am going over the following [tutorial](https://kluedo.ub.uni-kl.de/frontdoor/deliver/index/docId/4293/file/exact_fft_measurements.pdf). In section 2.1 the author says

> To calculate the $N$ point FFT the Matlab algorithm 1 can be used. Here, after taking the FFT, its magnitude is calculated and the bins are scaled by $1/N$.

Now the author doesn't explain as to why the bins are scaled by $1/N$. At first glance it looks like some kind of normalisation -- but why?

---

I did some further research and it seems there different ways to define the power in a signal, depending on what you are looking at. See slide 3 of this.

> http://www.hep.ucl.ac.uk/~rjn/saltStuff/fftNormalisation.pdf

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/31984/matlab-tt-fft-and-tt-ifft-scaling/31987#31987

Comment: @hotpaw2 by the looks of it yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, some kind of normalization needs to be done and it's a matter of convention which one to use. To explain, let $\mathbf{F}$ be a DFT matrix containing ${\rm e}^{-\jmath 2\pi \frac{mn}{N}}$. Then you can show that $\mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{F}^H = N \cdot \mathbf{I}_N$. This factor $N$ needs to be accounted for. Now, you can do either of the following:

- Define DFT via $\mathbf{D} = \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{d} \quad \rightarrow\quad$ IDFT becomes $\mathbf{d} = \frac 1N \mathbf{F}^H \cdot \mathbf{D}$.
- Define DFT via $\mathbf{D} = \frac 1N \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{d} \quad \rightarrow\quad$ IDFT becomes $\mathbf{d} =  \mathbf{F}^H \cdot \mathbf{D}$.
- Define DFT via $\mathbf{D} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{d} \quad \rightarrow\quad$ IDFT becomes $\mathbf{d} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \mathbf{F}^H \cdot \mathbf{D}$.

All three of them can be used and none of them is more or less correct than the other. Matlab uses the second one, Maple the third (if I remember correctly).

If you need the units to resemble Fourier integrals, normalizing by $\Delta t$ or $\Delta f$ can make sense as well, as you found in the slide set. Depends on what you want to do with the result really.

Comment: Thanks @Florian. Nice answer -- confirms what I have read elsewhere!

Comment: Glad to hear it helped! :)

Comment: Quantum, [here is another answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/31984/matlab-tt-fft-and-tt-ifft-scaling/31990#31990) that explicitly is about this whole scaling by $\frac1N$ issue.  It says what Florian says above but with the explicit summations.

Comment: Florian, i am unfamiliar with the "$H$" in "$\mathbf{F}^H$".  i take it to mean "**complex conjugate**" from the context, but I cannot say for sure.  What does that notation mean?

Comment: Yes it was supposed to mean conjugate (Hermitian) transpose.