# Different amplitude for different time resolution with FFT

Tags: matlab, fft, signal-analysis

In the following Matlab code, the amplitude of the spectral domain signal is printed

```
Temporal_Pulse_Width=1;
t=linspace(0,20,2000);
dt=t(2)-t(1);
Time_Period=round(Temporal_Pulse_Width/dt);
AA=zeros(length(t),1);
AA(Time_Period/2:3*Time_Period/2)=1;
A=20*log10(abs(fftshift(fft(AA/length(t)))));
frequencyAxis = ((0:length(t)-1) -ceil((length(t)-1)/2))/length(t)/(t(2)-t(1));
plot(frequencyAxis,A,'LineWidth',3);
max(A)
```

If we change the vector t as follows,

```
t=linspace(0,10,2000);
```

The result `(max(A))` will also change. How can I normalize the `fft` without having this problem?

Comment: If you search for "fft scaling" on this side, you'll really find a lot of answers to your question. Just one:

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MATLAB: $\tt fft$ and $\tt ifft$ scaling](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/31984/matlab-tt-fft-and-tt-ifft-scaling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in [MATLAB documentation for FFT](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html#buuutyt-5)

If you have `Y = fft(x)` then

$$Y_k = \sum_{j=1}^{N} x_j \cdot exp\left(-\frac{2 \pi i}{n} (k - 1)  (j - 1)\right)$$

$$x_j = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{N} X_k \cdot exp\left(+\frac{2 \pi i}{n} (k - 1)  (j - 1)\right)$$

Notice that the FFT is just a sum and the IFFT is divided by $n$, with this definition you know that  `fft(ifft(x)) = x`, but as the number of terms increase $Y_k$ will increase.

Your signal is a fixed duration pulse and you want a fixed amplitude in the frequency domain, so it is like an aperiodic Fourier transform

$$ \int x(t) exp\left( \frac{2\pi i}{n} u t \right) dt $$

A zero order approximation for this can be obtained by computing

```
A=20*log10(abs(fftshift(fft(AA*dt))));
```

For the pulse of width 1, `max(A)` will be `0dB` this way.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!

Comment: No problem, https://dsp.stackexchange.com/tour, if that solves, please accept the answer.